# InStock value does not change for configurable product after simple products has been sold

Tags: magento-1.7, out-of-stock

I have noticed that after all the simples products get quality 0 their Stock value automatically changes to out of stock. This is the way it is supposed to work in magento. However, I noticed that when I all the simples products have been sold, their stock value goes out of stock, but this value for the configurable product stays in stock. I ma not sure wether this is supposed to work like it. I was trying to find a way to set it to change out of stock as all the simple products get sold.

Is there a way to do it on the back end or do I have to do it programatically?

Magento ver 1.7.0.2

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the stock status to be out of stock? The reason I ask is, I'm pretty sure that the configurable will still obey the `Don't display out of stock products` setting. So in most cases it is functionally out of stock as `isSalable` returns false.

Comment: There is a reason. I ma using iWeb Auto Related Products
extension to display products from the same category. It uses stock filter to filter out the products and it displays the products that are long gone. This is the reason why I created this question.

Answer (score 1):

If simple products under the configurable are sold their individual stock will be updated as @Cags points out correctly(unless you've disabled this in the settings, but you wouldn't be asking this question I guess)

Configurables are not marked as is_qty items and are not set out of stock after selling a underlaying simple product.

After some further investigation it looks like there's a indexer for that. Did you check if the indexers are running, did your try a full reindex?

Otherwise there could be a problem related to the module from the third party you are using, maybe you should disable it and try it again, and maybe contact them if the problem is resolved after disabling. Disabling can be done by putting active on false in the `app/etc/modules/Module_Name.xml`

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed comment, I tried full reindexing and contacted the module developer who told me that the module uses instock filter to show only instock items. I also tried to disable and even reinstalling the module which did not give any results. I think I am going to edit the code for the module to rather than using instock filter to use qty => 1. Which is supposed to give the wanted outcome